# HBase scan and retrieve single columns

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to understand the data model that HBase uses in storing its data, in order to plan a more effective organization of application data. In particular I am trying to understand whether it is wise to plan to have a column family with a large number of columns - which will also vary between rows - knowing that I will need to read only a few columns at a time.

According to [this blog post](http://tech.flurry.com/2012/06/12/137492485/),

> HBase reads entire rows at a time, so while you can instruct the HBase
>   client to only return certain columns, this will not speed up your
>   queries

Now, as stated this is false, since you can certainly read the data from just one column family. Hence, substitute `entire rows` with `entire column families` in the above quote. Is this true?

That is: is it true that reading a single column in HBase will require to read the whole column family (regardless of what is actually returned to the client)? Does this change when performing a scan instead of a direct lookup?

Comment: To my understanding no, it just have to read the block where the column is stored, not the whole family. Also, according to the documentation it's recommended to keep the column families number as low as possible (http://hbase.apache.org/book/number.of.cfs.html)

Comment: @rmruano How does it locate the block then? Since each row can have a different set of columns, there is no predefined offset where to start reading. Does it have to traverse all the column family up to when it finds the column? Or tries to keep the columns sorted and locates the right one by, say, repeated bisection?

Comment: As far as I know, HBase is very efficient reading only just what it needs, so I'm pretty confident requesting just a few columns, being it a simple get or a full table scan. The location it's stored within the HFile index, you can find more information about it here: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/06/hbase-io-hfile-input-output/ & http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/hadoop-io-sequence-map-set-array-bloommap-files/